# C++ Cpr is not returning data when when using cmake build

Tags: c++, cmake, get, vcpkg

I am trying to run the CPR test project to make sure everything is running correctly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>

int main(int, char**) {

        cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://api.github.com/repos/whoshuu/cpr/contributors"},
                      cpr::Authentication{"user", "pass"},
                      cpr::Parameters{{"anon", "true"}, {"key", "value"}});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
    std::cout << r.text << std::endl;
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

After building out the project with CMake and running the cpr get request, my output does not return the get request information nor does it display any errors.

```
[main] Building folder: CmakeProject1 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: C:\Users\maste\Documents\Environment_Variables\cmake-3.23.1-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake --build c:/Users/maste/Desktop/CmakeProject1/build --config Debug --target run -j 10 --
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build]   main.cpp
[build]   ExampleHttp.vcxproj -> C:\Users\maste\Desktop\CmakeProject1\build\Debug\ExampleHttp.exe
[build]   
[build]   hello world
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

If I try running the code through the IDE it says cpr/cpr.h has no file directory.

```cpp
[Running] cd "c:\Users\maste\Desktop\CmakeProject1\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\maste\Desktop\CmakeProject1\"main
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: cpr/cpr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cpr/cpr.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.741 seconds
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(ExampleHttp VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(ExampleHttp main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

find_package(cpr CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(ExampleHttp PRIVATE cpr::cpr)

add_custom_target(run
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
    )
```

Comment: `cd "c:\Users\maste\Desktop\CmakeProject1\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\maste\Desktop\CmakeProject1\"main` your bug appears to be in your `tasks.json` since this line does not add an include directory for cpr or link to the library. Also you don't appear to be using CMake in VSCode. Have you enabled the cmake-tools extension? If you did can we see the CMakeLists.txt you have written for your application?

Comment: Yes, I have the cmake-tool enabled and here is the CmakeList.txt. `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(ExampleHttp VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(ExampleHttp main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

find_package(cpr CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(ExampleHttp PRIVATE cpr::cpr)

add_custom_target(run
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
    )
 `

Comment: It seems from the output you show in your question that CMake is not being called from VSCode to build your code when you debug. So I would check your cmake-tools setup to verify it is enabled and get it working: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)

Comment: I was using the IDE run code button to run the code. When using the CMake debug to run the code I do not receive any errors. As for the tasks.json, I did not have one so I just generated one but I do not know what to edit in it.

Comment: If setup correctly your VSCode should be able to use CMake and debug from the IDE using the same build command you used with CMake so you would not get the include path errors.

Comment: I think I'm explaining it wrong when using the button in the play button top right corner to run my code I get an error.  when using the play button on the bottom near the center of the screen I am not getting any errors but I'm also not getting the `r.text` information.

Comment: Your question showed multiple problems. The first problem you showed is with `cpr` not returning the data you expect. I can't help with that at all. You will have to wait on someone else for help with that. The second problem was a misconfiguration with the settings inside VSCode that is preventing you from debugging your CMake based project in the IDE. I was attempting to help you with this second problem because I believe that can and should be fixed and that will likely help you with future code.

Comment: I don't see the issue you say I have in my configuration. When I run the commands to build, run, delete cache and reconfigure, and debug they all work with no errors just not giving me the correct information. When I try running the code without the CMake tools at the bottom of the screen or through the command I'm getting a cpr/cpr.h file can not be found.

Comment: ***[Running] cd "c:\Users\maste\Desktop\CmakeProject1\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\maste\Desktop\CmakeProject1\"main
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: cpr/cpr.h: No such file or directory*** Is the issue I am talking about. If you had VSCode properly configured to build and have the debug task reference the build task from CMake this would work.

Comment: With all of this said you may have wanted to ask 2 separate questions. Since these 2 problems are completely unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error.
My CMakeList.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(your_target_name)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(your_target_name main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(cpr GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libcpr/cpr.git
        GIT_TAG 0817715923c9705e68994eb52ef9df3f6845beba)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cpr)

target_link_libraries(your_target_name PRIVATE cpr::cpr)
```

And the problem was that when I created a project in CLion, it set up a CMake profile like this
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwGrL.png)

Then I ran cmake generation and everything worked fine, but after restarting ide i got this:

```
CMake Error: Error: generator : MinGW Makefiles Does not match the generator used previously: Ninja
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.
```

So the solution was to recreate the project with the Ninja generator initially set in the CMake profile settings like this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWlXU.png)